# mysql helm aks keeps crashing

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, helm, aks

I tried to install mysql using helm chart

```
helm install mysql --set mysqlRootPassword=medone,mysqlUser=mysql,mysqlPassword=medone,mysqlDatabase=profil,persistence.existingClaim=mysql-pv-claim  stable/mysql
```

when i tried to connect to the pod it gives me as status **CrashLoopBackOff** i checked the logs for the pod and i found this log but i didn't understand the issue here :

```
2020-04-13 11:37:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.28-1debian9 started.
    2020-04-13 11:37:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
    2020-04-13 11:37:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.28-1debian9 started.
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.020945Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.043344Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.28) starting as process 1 ...
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.129278Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.129403Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.129417Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.129422Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.129426Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.129430Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.129728Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.129864Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.132198Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.140415Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.142817Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
    2020-04-13T11:37:46.350879Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4800!
    2020-04-13 11:37:46 0x7f49ef9fc740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139955529566016 in file ut0ut.cc line 918
    InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
    InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
    InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
    InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
    InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
    InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
    InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
    11:37:46 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
    This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
    or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
    or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
    Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
    As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
    collection process might fail.
    key_buffer_size=8388608
    read_buffer_size=131072
    max_used_connections=0
```

Comment: Have you tried without `persistence.existingClaim=mysql-pv-claim`? Please try running this `helm install mysql --set mysqlRootPassword=medone,mysqlUser=mysql,mysqlPassword=medone,mysqlDatabase=profil stable/mysql`

Comment: @mWatney it works without , however i needed a persistentVolumeClaim for the database , so when i add the persistence.existingClaim arg it crashes .

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have data on this PVC that you want to use in this new mysql is that right or this PVC is empty? If you have data on it, there is something on this data making the mysql to crash. I would suggest you to bring this mysql up without the `mysql-pv-claim` and add it in a different path by editing the deployment and inspect this data looking for what is making mysql to crash.

Comment: If you don't include `persistence.existingClaim=mysql-pv-claim`, the chart will create a PVC for you instead of using the predefined one.

Comment: @mWatney The predifined pvc that i am using  is from an `azure file share (PV)` that i have created and it is empty ,therefore there is no data  that can affect the creation of the mysql chart i think

Comment: There is something wrong with your PVC. I tested here with the equivalent on GCP and it works as designed. Please, can you  update your question including the output for `kubectl get pvc mysql-pv-claim -o yaml`. You can also attach this PVC to another Pod and try to write/read from this PVC. It is possible?